# ponteiros C tratados em python

Tags: python, c, ponteiro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");

    int *x,valor,y;
    valor = 35;
    x = &valor;
    y = *x;

    printf("o endereço da variavel valor: %p\n", &valor);
    printf("endereço da variavel ponteiro x: %p\n", &x);
    printf("conteudo da variavel apontada por x: %d\n", x);
    printf("conteudo da variavel comum y: %d\n", y);    
}
```

Eu desejo fazer esse código rodar dentro de um programa em *python*. Como faço?
Estou iniciando em *python* mas quero trabalhar com ponteiros mesclando as linguagens, pois até então não achei como fazer isso somente com *python*.

Answer (score 1):

*A grosso modo*, dentro do modelo de dados padrão do Python, ponteiros podem ser encarados como uma analogia ao conceito de [Identidade de Objetos](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html), essa identidade é representa por um número inteiro e pode ser obtida por meio da função nativa [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#id).

O conteúdo de objetos também podem ser recuperados através do seu identificador por meio do método [`cast()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.cast) disponibilizado pela biblioteca padrão [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html).

Veja só como o seu código poderia ser reescrito em Python:

```
import ctypes

# Valor
val = 35

# Recupera a identidade de "Valor"
x = id(val)

# A partir da identidade de "Valor"
# eh possivel recuperar o seu conteudo
y = ctypes.cast( x, ctypes.py_object ).value

print(val);
print(x);
print(y);
```